# Is "まひろとアバ X 于ユール" in the image? What is ' X ' in the image?

Tags: meaning, kanji, kana

What character is in `X` position on the image?

> まひろとアバ`X`チュール

Maybe that is `アバコ`?

[image: "まひろとアバ X 于ユール"]

Comment: `That is 'チョ'(tyo)` <-- 「チ**ュ** (chu)」です。ョ→ュ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 「ン」.

「アバンチュール」 is the "French-Japanese" version of 「アドベンチャー」.  Think of it as the "adventure in the love department".  "aventure" vs "adventure".

"***Adventure with Mahiro***"

Another love-related "French vs. English" pair of katakana words you need to know to be fluent in Japanese is:

「アベック」vs.「カップル」

Comment: Thank you, Is still 'love-related' with the 'Adventure' word when ignore [the origin context](https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=66484961)?in other word: I can't understand the 'love-related' meaning when ignore that origin context.

Answer (score 2):

That would be an ん in Katagana form: ン

So your title would be:

> まひろとアバンチュール

In the font presented there the コ katagana would retain its connected-ness otherwise it would be too similar to the ん（ン）.

I know different fonts in Japanese can usually throw you off sometimes, but don't worry, keep reading and exposing yourself to new formats and you'll see the patterns in time.

*EDIT: チュル -> チュール, my bad. Thanks @Chocolate

Comment: `アバンチュル` じゃなくて「アバンチュ**ー**ル」.... ( `your sentence` -- 文じゃないし..)